# change value in a variable and change wrong instantly in other variable

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have a class and I am taking 2 instance form that like

```
List<MyClass> lstMyClassTemp;

List<MyClass> lstMyClass = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

after initial some value or change some thing in `lstMyClass`  I will update the value of temp variable *lstMyClassTemp* by a function `Update()`

```
private void update1()
{
   lstMyClassTemp = new ArrayList<MyClass>(lstMyClass);
}
```

now my problem is before I run update function when I change some value in the `lstMyClass` variable the value of `lstMyClassTemp` variable change immediately but it is not true 
please let me know what part could made problem

**Edit and Update**

Thanks for your answers

your answers are useful in continue I get new error and problem when I am changing value in `lstMyClass` the value in the `lstMyClassTemp` change immediately which part can make a problem?

```
lstMyClassTemp = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

for (i = 0; i < lstMyClass.size; i++) {
    lstMyClassTemp.add((MyClass)lstMyClass.get(i));
}

// ... other code ...

int rowIStr=0;

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if(lstMyClassTemp .get(j).getTempName().equals(lstMyClassTemp.get(rowIStr).getName()))
        lstMyClass.get(j).setName("Alex");
}
rowIStr++

// ... other code ...

update1();
```

Comment: When you change some value in lstMyClass then value of lstMyClassTemp variable change but it is not true? Add your code or add more information. You wrote that: or change some thing in lstMyClass I will update the value of temp variable lstMyClassTemp ... So what is problem?

Comment: thanks for your attention imagine MYClass is contain id,name,state by contractor , get and set method  the by code like for ( p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
     if(lstMyClassTemp.get(p).getState()==true)
      lstMyClass.get(p).setState(false); tempFlag=true} after that if tempFlag is true I am calling the update function but problem is in the first condtion if it is true before I call update() the temp variable change

Comment: tanks for your helping but I have an new problem in my code and I don't understand why ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find a way that is easy and useful I am putting that here I hope it will be helpful for another time :)

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {

/** some method  ***/

    public Object clone() {  
        try { 
       return super.clone(); 

        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) { 

            e.printStackTrace();  
            return null; 
        } 
     } 
}
```

in main body code :

```
ArrayList<MyClass> lstMyClassTemp= new ArrayList<MyClass>();
ArrayList<MyClass> lstMyClass= new ArrayList<MyClass>();
for(MyClass m: lstMyClass){
lstMyClassTemp.add((MyClass)m.clone()); 
}
```

the main part is cloning

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5x1S.png)

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor of `ArrayList` only copies the direct contents of the ols ArrayList. It does not perform deep copies of the objects inside the ArrayList. Calling the copy contructor is the same as:

```
List<MyClass> lstMyClassTemp = new ArrayList<>();
for(MyClass m: lstMyClass){
    lstMyClassTemp.add(m);
}
```

So the new ArrayList contains the same references to objects of the type `MyClass` as the old one, but still only references.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
lstMyClassTemp= new ArrayList<MyClass>(lstMyClass);
```

you create an exact copy in `lstMyClassTemp` of the *references* to the objects in `lstMyClass`. So `lstMyClassTemp` and `lstMyClass` refer to different lists, but those two lists contain references to the *same* objects. Therefore, when you do:

```
lstMyClass.get(j).setName("Alex");
```

then you must remember that `lstMyClass.get(j)` returns a reference to the same object as `lstMyClassTemp.get(j)`. Not a copy of the object, but the same actual object. Therefore, when you set the name of that object, you can see the changes by using both `lstMyClass.get(j)` and `lstMyClassTemp.get(j)`, since they are the same object.

Comment: thanks I edit the peace of code actually I need a temp list of my last value to check those value in a condition in this way please le me know your idea

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the creation method you used passes the reference to the variable instead of simply copying it. Since Java does not have pointers you will have to manually copy it yourself. Here's an example of how you might do that.

```
lstMyClassTemp = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

for (i = 0; i < lstMyClass.size; i++) {
  lstMyClassTemp.add((MyClass)lstMyClass.get(i));
}
```